# How to auto fit recyclerview items to the width of screen android?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to implement below layout. I want to position the items in such a way that it takes full width of the screen:

Expected Layout:
[image]

Actual Layout:

[image]

This is the code for item of my Recyclerview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

  <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/size_8dp"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/size_20dp"
    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/size_20dp"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/size_8dp">

    <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/legendsItemIcon"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/text_legend_status_name"
      />
    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/text_legend_status_name"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      tools:text="Low"
      android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_8sp"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/legendsItemIcon"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/legendsItemIcon"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/legendsItemIcon"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
      android:textColor="@color/legends_item_status_text_color"
      android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/size_4dp"
      />

  </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Is your recyclerview is in horizontal orientation?

Comment: do you want to align each recyclerview row items to left(start) ?

Comment: @DhavalSolanki yes

Comment: I want to expand them to the screen's width @Fartab

Comment: do you have two items in each row? and want each one to expand to half of parent's width?

Comment: do you want to have a 3 items in each row and  repeat it in vertical recycler view?

Comment: Its can have more then that @nicej

Comment: I have a child `RecyclerView` inside a parent `RecyclerView`

Comment: How many items can a row have? is it scroll-able?

Comment: Yeah it is scrollable @user10284284

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This custom class will help you https://gist.github.com/heinrichreimer/39f9d2f9023a184d96f8

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class SpanningLinearLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager {

public SpanningLinearLayoutManager(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public SpanningLinearLayoutManager(Context context, int orientation, boolean reverseLayout) {
    super(context, orientation, reverseLayout);
}

public SpanningLinearLayoutManager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.LayoutParams generateDefaultLayoutParams() {
    return spanLayoutSize(super.generateDefaultLayoutParams());
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.LayoutParams generateLayoutParams(Context c, AttributeSet attrs) {
    return spanLayoutSize(super.generateLayoutParams(c, attrs));
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.LayoutParams generateLayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp) {
    return spanLayoutSize(super.generateLayoutParams(lp));
}

@Override
public boolean checkLayoutParams(RecyclerView.LayoutParams lp) {
    return super.checkLayoutParams(lp);
}

private RecyclerView.LayoutParams spanLayoutSize(RecyclerView.LayoutParams layoutParams){
    if(getOrientation() == HORIZONTAL){
        layoutParams.width = (int) Math.round(getHorizontalSpace() / (double) getItemCount());
    }
    else if(getOrientation() == VERTICAL){
        layoutParams.height = (int) Math.round(getVerticalSpace() /  (double) getItemCount());
    }
    return layoutParams;
}

@Override
public boolean canScrollVertically() {
    return false;
}
@Override
public boolean canScrollHorizontally() {
    return false;
}

private int getHorizontalSpace() {
    return getWidth() - getPaddingRight() - getPaddingLeft();
}

private int getVerticalSpace() {
    return getHeight() - getPaddingBottom() - getPaddingTop();
}
}
```

Set RecyclerView layoutManager to SpanningLinearLayoutManager to instead of LinearLayoutManager

Comment: It's close enough. How can I evenly distribute the items and still make the content scrollable? I have more then 10 items and it will get really close to each other. @SSB

Comment: @SSB can you look this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71380874/11560810)

Comment: Works like wonders.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly  you need a horizontal recycler view..
So set your layout manager as below:

```
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mHorizontalLayoutManager);
```

if your items have been more than your screen size it will scrollable

Comment: Hey. can you look this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71380874/11560810)

Answer (score 0):

You simply use GridLayoutManager instead of LinearLayoutManager

```
 /**
 * Creates a vertical GridLayoutManager
 *
 * @param context Current context, will be used to access resources.
 * @param spanCount The number of columns in the grid
 */
public GridLayoutManager(Context context, int spanCount) {
    super(context);
    setSpanCount(spanCount);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want Recyclerview wrap its content (full height stretch wrap its content). Just wrap it with NestedScrollView. I tested and its work.

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  >

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <!-- This Recyclerview will fit content.
    So it become full height stretch wrap its content-->
    <RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Bayar SPP"
        style="@style/FontStyleSubtitle"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/recyclerView" />

   </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
recyclerView.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(context, splitcount)
```

This worked for me.