# How to fill item width children in reyclerview android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-linearlayout, android-constraintlayout

Hey I am working in android. I want to fit children in whole view of recyclerview android. I have horizontal recylerview. I will show what I want in diagram.

**Scenario 1**

when I have more item in recyclerview, I want to show children like this in my recycler view.

**Expected Output**

[image]

**Scenario 2**

when I have **three** item I want to show like this. It will fill whole view in reyclerview.

**Expected Output**

[image]

**Scenario 3**

When I have **Two** item in reyclerview, I need to look like this

**Expected Output**

[image]

The problem I am getting that I have 3 item, the view is not filling fully. Actually I want to stretch whole view to full width like **Scenario 2**.

**Actual output**

[image]

**item_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/drawable_selector"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/subText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/tagContainer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tagText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingStart="10dp"
            android:paddingEnd="10dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

**UPDATE**

after @Cheticamp suggestion I did this code

```
companion object {
        fun bindView(parent: ViewGroup): XYZViewHolder {
            val view = XyzLayoutBinding.inflate(
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
                parent,
                false
            )
            val lp = view.container.layoutParams
            lp.width = parent.measuredWidth / 3
            return OptionsViewHolder(
                view
            )
        }
    }
```

As you can see my last item is cut from the end.

[image]

I think in my framelayout i Used **marginEnd** 10 dp is it causing issue? please refer my layout if you need more. And one more thing I didn't divide framelayout instead I take linear layout as **container**. I am adding my github [link](https://github.com/vivek-modi/OptionsView).

Comment: This looks like a job for ViewPager instead of RecyclerView. I’ve never personally used ViewPager, though.

Comment: thanks @Tenfour04 I'll check that with viewpager

Comment: You can getItemCount, and use that to set the child item width programmatically, if 2, 50%, if three 3 33.3% else default

Comment: @SABANTO can you give me idea how can I set programmatically?

Comment: If XyzLayout is the item_layout.xml then the space available to your items is the width of the FrameLayout minus is end margin (10dp). As a result, you items are each 3.33dps too long which manifests in the last item in the row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the width of the *RecyclerView* item views in `onCreateViewHolder()`. The *ViewGroup* parent is the *RecyclerView*.

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_view, parent, false)
    val lp = view.layoutParams
    // Change the width of the item view here
    lp.width = parent.measuredWidth / 3 // width is 1/3 of the width of the RecyclerView
    return ItemViewHolder(view)
}
```

Comment: Hey @Cheticamp I have reyclerview `marginStart` and `StartEnd`  16dp should I need to **add** them or **subtract** them in `width`. Because my view is cut on right side of screen.

Comment: what about `scenario 3` ? I changed to  `lp.width = parent.measuredWidth / 2 ` it looks weird.

Comment: @vivekmodi Weird how?

Comment: @vivekmodi Margins on the item view belong to the _RecyclerView_, so the available space is the width of the _RecyclerView_ _less_ the sum of the start/end margins.

Comment: I update the code and image please have a look.

Comment: I added my sample repository. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1):

**Customize frameLayout class**
make a class inherit FrameLayout or another layout you use.

```
    public class SquareFrameLayout extends FrameLayout {
    public SquareFrameLayout(@NonNull Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public SquareFrameLayout(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public SquareFrameLayout(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    public SquareFrameLayout(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
    }
}
```

onMeasure method is important.

then change root layout item recyclerView to SquareFrameLayout (The class built now)
like this:

```
<com.example.app.SquareFrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/background_rv_item"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

   
   //your items

</com.example.app.SquareFrameLayout>
```

Comment: it's not working, As what I expect it showing me single item at once.

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox-layout library provided by Google.
You can adjust the items according to your need.
Download the app and see this demo working for you or not. https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout